# Should I put openjpa dependency in openjpa maven plugin if it is already in dependencies?

Tags: maven, dependencies, openjpa

I use OpenJPA as a JPA provider.

I put this dependency in *pom.xml*

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
        <artifactId>openjpa-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and the openjpa-maven-plugin

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>**/entities/*.class</includes>
                <addDefaultConstructor>true</addDefaultConstructor>
                <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enhancer</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Should I put openJPA dependency again in the plugin if it's already in pom.xml? What purpose it has?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Put dependencies in plugin configuration is necessary if you need a specific dependency not in your project dependency.

I don't known openjpa usage but in your example the dependency in your pom is not exactly the same of dependency in your plugin configuration. So if plugin class need is not same class in openjpa-all artifact you need to kept plugin dependency.

Comment: Thank you for reply. openjpa-all contains that dependency that is used in plugin so as I understand dependency in plugin is not necessary, right?

Comment: no in your caseyou need to put this dependency in plugin configuration